# Sniff a specific connection

Tags: sockets, network-programming, reverse-engineering, sniffing, network-security

I have found many code examples for sniffing packets through the network, but I am wondering if there is a way to sniff a specific local connection without having to filter by ip or port number. Assuming it will be lighter with less computation.

Comment: can you please specify what do you mean by local connection(is it a LAN, are you running some service on localhost, or something else?), and what have you been looking at?

Comment: by local I meant, connection outgoing from my local host to some other host on the network,

Comment: operating system, programming language, and example code?

Comment: os linux,  programming lanuage any one (c/python/..). for the example code i don't know what you mean of it, to explain my self more, i know that i can create a raw socket and receive with it all the incoming packet, but if i do so, i will need to filter among all the packets, specific packets with a specifique (ip,port), what i want, of course if it is possible, to receive/sniff only the packet in/outgouing from a port number.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a hypothetical solution, forward the the packet to a socket that read the packet then transfer it to it destination by an other socket, like an internal middel man, witch is a heavy and less dynamic solution it will need an interaction with the kernel, :/